# Получить признак наличия найденного адреса из яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Всем привет!
Есть карта Яндекс с кластеризатором и наброшенными метками.

На самой карте есть стандартная строка поиска адреса яндекса.

Каждый раз, когда пользователь выполняет функцию, мне надо проверять - искал ли он адрес через яндексовский поиск (т.е. есть ли метка на карте), центрирвоать карту к этой метке и приближать по-максимуму.

Не могу найти как обратиться к карте и получить координаты точки, которую искал пользователь.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/searchControl-docpage/#searchControl__results тут ответа на ваш вопрос нет?

Comment: С этого начал, не нашел( 
Или смотрю криво или нет там решения моей задачи(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, речь об элементе управления "Поиск по карте" (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/ ).

В обработчике события выбора результата поиска можно получить координаты точки, которую нашел и выбрал пользователь, вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/naivv/mqf6pj72/ (API ключ из песочницы здесь не работает).

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.74, 37.58],
    zoom: 13,
    controls: []
  });

  // Создадим экземпляр элемента управления «поиск по карте»
  // с установленной опцией провайдера данных для поиска по организациям.
  var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
      provider: 'yandex#search'
    }
  });

  myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

  // Программно выполним поиск определённых кафе в текущей
  // прямоугольной области карты.
  searchControl.search('Шоколадница');

  console.log('request: ' + searchControl.getRequestString());

  // обработка событий элемента управления "Поиск по карте"
  searchControl.events.add('resultselect', function(e) {
    console.log('resultselect event fired:');
    //console.log(e);
    var target = e.get('target');
    //console.log(target);
    var found = searchControl.getResultsCount(); //target.state.get('found');
    console.log('results found: ' + found);
    var index = searchControl.getSelectedIndex(); //e.get('index');
    var results = searchControl.getResultsArray(); //target.state.get('results');
    if (results.length) {
      var result = results[index]; //getResult(index)
      //console.log(result.properties);
      var coords = result.geometry.getCoordinates();
      //TODO делаем что планировали с координатами найденной точки
      console.log('selected coordinates: ' + coords);
      var name = result.properties.get('name');
      console.log('selected name: ' + name);
      var description = result.properties.get('description');
      console.log('selected description: ' + description);
    } else {
      console.log('empty result!');
    }
    console.log("\n");
  });
  searchControl.events.add('submit', function(e) {
    console.log('submit event fired:');
    console.log("\n");
  });
  searchControl.events.add('load', function(e) {
    console.log('load event fired:');
    console.log("\n");
  });
  searchControl.events.add('resultshow', function(e) {
    console.log('resultshow event fired:');
    console.log("\n");
  });
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Поиск организаций и геопоиск</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=60445215-6d3a-4f88-87fe-8d52b72e5bc9" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```